# Jquery form data passes empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, request

I have an ajax call, Where on the submit button click the ajax call initiates

```
<form id="editPet" method="patch" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    inputs...

    <button id="updatePet" data-id="{{ $pet->uuid }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" type="button">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Ajax call :

```
$('#updatePet').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let petId = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});
    $.ajax({
        url: "/my/pet/update/" + petId,
        type: "patch",
        data: new FormData($("#editPet")[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            // Do something
        },
        error: function(error) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
});
```

**On the server side i am getting the request with `dd($request->all())` which is empty array.**

What am i missing here ?

Comment: can you add your server side also `$("#editPet")[0]` this should get value? should probably be `$("#editPet").val()`

Comment: No we cannot add `$("#editPet").val()` to php, Its juqery syntax. If i got you correct

Comment: not in php in your ajax request.`new FormData($("#editPet")[0])`

Comment: Check Preserve Log in Developer Tools and look at request payload. Then you will know on which side it is...

Comment: @guradio `$("#editPet").val()` is empty.

Comment: @bigless preserve log is not present there.

Comment: Check out Network tab in Developer Tools. Atleast in Chrome, there is.

Comment: @guradio `new FormData($("#editPet")[0])` is passing to FormData the form element, which is valid for the constructor.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: Try taking off `processData: false`.  *"By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false."*  You are giving it a FormData element for data.  You want it to turn that into a query string on the request.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by removing :

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

As @Taplar mentioned in the comment,

> "By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"